# Sequelize How to delete an occurence in an association table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having two tables user and group, a manytomany relation between them, thereofre a third table group_has_user 
given a user I'm trying to remove some groups,
I tried :

```
Model.User.findOne({
    where: {
        "id": POST.id
    },
    include: [Model.Project]
}).then(function (user) {
    user.Project.destroy({
        where:{
            "id": ids
        }
    })
})
```

> where id is the user id and ids, is a list of groups that I wan to
>   remove

but this code doesn't works, project is undefined, and also I don't think that what I want could be done this way, can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Projects you want to remove and then call the generated `removeProject` method on each project you got:

```
Model.User.findOne({
  where: {
    "id": POST.id
  },
  include: [Model.Project]
}).then(function (user) {
  Model.Projcet.find({
    where: {
      id: {
        [Op.in]: ids
      }
    }
  }).then(projectsToRemove => {
    projectsToRemove.forEach(p => {
      await user.removeProject(p);
    })
  })
})
```

Source: [Official documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#associating-objects)

Comment: thank you for your response, however, I don't want to remove all the project on which the given user works, I just want to remove some of them (I have a list of preject ids' to be removed)

Comment: I think that this solution will have an impact on performance, since it will go back and forth between my app and the DB, I use another solution (even though I think it's not clean ), I work directly on the association table : `Model.UserHasGroup/destroy({where....})`